# Core Data vs NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfilemanager

**The problem:**

I have been using for some time now my own cache system by using `NSFileManager`. Normally the data I receive is JSON and I just save the dictionary directly into cache (in the Documents Folder). When I need it back I will just go get it. I also implement, sometimes when I feel it's better, a `NSDictionary` on the root Folder with keys/values for the path for a given resource. For example:

Resource about weather in Geneve 17/02/2013, so I would have a key called GE_17_02_2013 and the value the path to the `NSDictionary` with the information.

Normally I don't need to do any complex queries. But, somehow, and from what I have been reading, when you have a lot of data, you should stick with Core Data. In my case, I normally have a lot of data, but I never actually felt the application going down, or suffering in terms of performance. So my questions are:

1. In this case, where sometimes (the weather thing was just an
       example) I need to just remove all the data (a Twitter feed, for
       example) and replace it by a completely new stream of data, is Core
       Data worth? I think removing all the data, and inserting (populating) it, is heavier than just store the `NSDictionary` and replacing the old one.
2. Sometimes it would envolve images, textFiles, etc and the
       `NSFileManager` does it perfectly, so what advantages could Core
       Data bring in this cases?

**P.S:** I just saw [this](http://biasedbit.com/filesystem-vs-coredata-image-cache/) post, where this kind of question is made and numbers prove which one is actually faster. Still, I would like as well an empiric answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Data is worth using in every scenario you described. In fact, if an app stores more than preferences, you should probably use Core Data. Here are some reasons, among which, you'll find answers to your own problems:

- is definitely faster than the filesystem, even if you wipe out everything and write it again as you describe (so you don't benefit to much from caching). This is basically because you can coalesce your operations and only access the store when needed. So if you read, write and read, you can save only once, the rest is done in memory, which is, needless to say, very fast.
- everything is versioned and you can migrate from one version to another easily (while keeping the content the user has on the device)
- 80% of your model operations come free. Like, when something changes, you can override the `willSave` managed object method and notify your controllers.
- using `cascade` makes it trivial to delete even very complex object structures
- while is a bad idea to keep images in the database, you can still keep them on the filesystem and have core data delete them automatically when the managed object that represents them is deleted
- is flexible, in fact is so flexible that you could migrate your project from using the local filesystem to using a server with very little modifications by writing a custom data store.
- the core data designer basically creates the model objects for you. You don't need to create your own model classes (which you would have to if using the filesystem)

Comment: the cache is more for offline scenarios. So in normal conditions with internet access, I normally replace the stored data very frequently, that's why I had concerns. Another advantage, is the fact of just using an `NSDictionary` and not having the need to know what's inside of him (how he is composed). Would it make sense to have `NSManagedObject` with only a `NSDictionary`?

Comment: The cache is important for local filesystem as well. The filesystem access is way slower than memory access. I'm not sure why you don't have the need to know what's inside that dictionary, don't you read/interpret it as some point. If you only store a file like any other, which happens to be a serialized dictionary, then yes, there's no point in using Core Data

Comment: I mean, I Know what's inside, but if for some reason an API changes, and add different things, I am not constrained to that.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case ... is Core Data worth it?

Yes, to the extent that you need something more centrally managed than trying to draw up your own file-system schema.  Core Data, and its lower-level cousin SQL, are still the best choice for persistence that we have right now.  Besides, the performance hit of using `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` to keep serializing/deserializing a dictionary over and over again becomes increasingly noticeable with larger datasets.

> I think removing all the data, and inserting (populating) it, is heavier
>   than just store the NSDictionary and replacing the old one.

Absolutely, yes.  But, you don't have to think about cache turnover like that.  If  you imagine Core Data as a static model, you can use a cache layer to ferry data in and out of the store.  Need that resource about the weather?  Check the cache layer.  If it's not in there, make the cache run a fetch request.  Need to turn over the whole cache?  Have the cache empty itself then run a request to mark every entity with some kind of flag to show they are invalid.  The expensive deletion you're worrying about can be done by a background process when you see that all your new data has been safely interned in the cache.

> Sometimes it would envolve images, textFiles, etc and the
>   NSFileManager does it perfectly, so what advantages could Core Data
>   bring in this cases?

Unfortunately, not many.  For blobs of data (which is essentially what Core Data does in these situations), storage and fetches to and from Core Data can quickly get costly.  They can also take up a noticeably larger space on disk if they aren't compressed (which further decreases performance).  If you need a faster alternative, use a store more suited to the task like [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) or [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), and use the entities in the Core Data store as a kind of stand-in that would, say, contain the key to the resource in one of those relational databases.

Comment: I use that mechanism (invalidation) with the `NSFileManager` approach. With big amounts of data. Thanks for the input Robert.